# concurrent DB calls using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I am trying to improve performance of the dashboard page of my app .It's a spring boot app and hibernate is used for Dao layer.
I need to fetch count of participants against 5 different alert type(basically filters).

I am trying to initiate DB queries concurrently so far I have done this:

```
  Map<Long,CompletableFuture<Long>> furtureMap = new HashMap<>();
      Map<Long, Long> alertMap = new HashMap<>();
      if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(alertList)) {

        for(AlertMasterI18N alertMasterI18N : alertList) {
          dashboardFilterDto.setAlertId(alertMasterI18N.getAlertMaster().getId());
          setDatesForDashboardFilterDto(dashboardFilterDto);
          CompletableFuture<Long> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
              return dashboardDao.getParticipantsCount(dashboardFilterDto);
            } catch (DaoException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0L;
          });
          furtureMap.put(alertMasterI18N.getAlertMaster().getId(), future);
        }
       /* CompletableFuture.allOf(furtureMap.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture[furtureMap.size()])).get(); */
       furtureMap.entrySet().stream().forEach( entry -> {
         entry.getValue().thenAccept( count -> alertMap.put(entry.getKey(),count));
       });
      }
```

Somehow I am getting quite weird results than that of a results I was getting by executing them sequentially. Same count is returned for all alert sometimes it's 0 while if I revert the code its giving correct results.
I have also tried using CompletableFuture.allOf and callig get() on it but that time the count for all alerts it consistently 0.

this first time I am trying my hands on asynch programming
Could anyone please let me know is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: can you share this code dashboardDao.getParticipantsCount(dashboardFilterDto) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the DAO layer is all good, the only missing point that I am able to see in the provided code is call to `get()` or `join()` at end. Without this call, none of the `CompletableFuture` will actually execute.

Following outline add all the ***newly*** created `CompletableFuture` in last forEach loop and then wait for them all afterward.

```
    Map<Long,CompletableFuture<Long>> furtureMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, Long> alertMap = new HashMap<>();
    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(alertList)) {

        for (AlertMasterI18N alertMasterI18N : alertList) {
            dashboardFilterDto.setAlertId(alertMasterI18N.getAlertMaster().getId());
            setDatesForDashboardFilterDto(dashboardFilterDto);
            CompletableFuture<Long> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    return dashboardDao.getParticipantsCount(dashboardFilterDto);
                } catch (DaoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0L;
            });
            furtureMap.put(alertMasterI18N.getAlertMaster().getId(), future);
        }
        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> finalCollector = new ArrayList<>();
        /* CompletableFuture.allOf(furtureMap.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture[furtureMap.size()])).get(); */
        furtureMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
            finalCollector.add(entry.getValue()
                    .thenAccept(count -> alertMap.put(entry.getKey(), count)));
        });
        /* Wait for all the results */
        CompletableFuture
                .allOf(finalCollector.toArray(new CompletableFuture[finalCollector.size()]))
                .join();
    }
```

If this doesn't work then most likely something is wrong within DAO layer which is causing async execution failing (while succeeding in sequential execution). Sharing how you are fetching data in your DAO layer will shed further light on source of the problem.